# How to reduce the threat to life of a nocturnal parasite-like creature

Tags: magic, fauna, mythical-creatures

In this world there is a giant cloud of dust permanently on top of this continent, it makes it hard for sunlight to reach said continent, also there are only two giant continents on each side of the world.

The creatures can take over other animals, this is the way they can survive, by using their new host to feed on other animals meat, including other animals possessed by this creature when food is scarce. Their host's body gets bigger, and overall the creature is dangerous independently of whatever animal it took over and when it is night time they become more dangerous. Most of them are concentrated in the dark continent, but over the years some have migrated to the other continent where humans live.

What I would like to know is how I could make them irrelevant without killing off all the planet. Also, they are not a main threat to the story, but they are a constant threat that can't be forgotten about.

In this world Humanity has access to steampunk-like technology.

Comment: I have an Idea, but this depends on what the main threat is.

Comment: @ALEXZANDERNORONHA-HYDE-STUD so far there is none, I am still building the world, but I thought those creatures could help to give humans something to fight when going to the dark continent, although there is another creature I had in mind, it is a stronger form of the one mentioned here, it is like a shadow, only lives in dark places and has no shape, they can't take over hosts and they are way more dangerous than the nocturnal parasites that are a weaker variant of that shadow creature.

Comment: I am feeling the need t start asking 20 Q re this parasite. Bigger than a bread bx? Etc.

Comment: How do these parasites enter the hosts' body? How big are they? How long can they possess a host? Are there prerequesites for the host to be possessed? How intelligent are these parasites? Another thing to consider: How dangerous do you want them to be? Are they only a nuisance, or a serious threat to civilication?

Comment: @DarthDonut They are in a gas state, they just enter their hosts through their pores,  and take control of their nervous system, they stronger they are the bigger they get to grow (once possessing a host), so in that sense not all are that dangerous but there are some big ones out there! They change their hosts body making it bigger, darker and enhancing the animal´s characteristics. The parasites are not that intelligent but they use their host's instincts, their only goal is to survive and if needed the stronger ones can swap host, but it drains a lot of energy so they would rather run away

Comment: Since I can't write an answer due to unclear I'll write it here. (I don't think it was that unclear). The parasite can only enter a host during high humidity, cold but not freezing night, a common flower is in bloom or insert other limiting conditions. If chance of infection is reduced due to the environment then the parasite might be devastating if infected but chances are that conditions will never be right for you to be infected. Since they live in dark places maybe the conditions need to mimic a deep cave perfectly.